# i am writing a wrapper class . error showing Entity is not api accessible

Tags: apex, pageblock

This is class

```
public class Displayprods1 {    
    public List<OpportunityLineItem> proList{get;set;}
    public list<wrapper1> wrp{get;set;}
    List<OpportunityLineItemwrapper> OppList = new List<OpportunityLineItemwrapper>();
    public Displayprods1(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    }
    public void populate(){
        list<product> plist = [select id,Quantity,ListPrice,TotalPrice from OpportunityLineItem limit10];
        for(product pr:plist){
            wrapper1 w1 = new wrapper1();
            w1.name = pr.name;
            w1.Quantity = pr.Quantity;
            w1.ListPrice = pr.ListPrice;
            w1.TotalPrice = pr.TotalPrice;
            wrp.add(w1);
                }
    }
}
-------------------------------------------------------------------
wrapper class
public class OpportunityLineItemwrapper {
// all the line record instance create
        public OpportunityLineItem pro{get; set;} 
        public  string name {get;set;}
        public  integer Quantity {get;set;} // number
        public  decimal ListPrice {get;set;} // currency
        public  decimal TotalPrice {get;set;} // currency 
        public  Boolean selected {get; set;} // true
        public OpportunityLineItemwrapper()
        {      
               name  = '';
               Quantity = 0 ;
               ListPrice = 0 ;
               TotalPrice = 0;
        }

}
```

Comment: which line reports the error? what have you done to try and narrow down the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Probably this:

```
list<product> plist = ...
for(product pr:plist){
```

that should be:

```
list<OpportunityLineItem> plist = ...
for (OpportunityLineItem pr:plist){
```

Including a type name `Product` in code produces that error.

Comment: Constructor not defined: [wrapper1].<Constructor>(); showing error

Comment: @bingi Unfortunately the Apex compiler stops at the first error. So if your code contains multiple errors, when you fix one the next one will appear. You will have to work through each in turn.

Comment: ok . wrapper1 all ready create an instace of objective but they showing error